# ¿Como puedo operar los elementos de un objeto que tienen una propiedad común, para hacer un ranking? en NodeJS, Express, Mongo (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, jsonobject

Estoy trabajando con NodeJs y Express y Mongo para hacer una web con un ranking basado en múltiples entradas por múltiples usuarios.

Tengo lo siguiente en la DB:

Notas:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "pages" : 5, "user" : "Mike"},
{ "_id" : 2, "pages" : 10, "user" : "Juanito"},
{ "_id" : 3, "pages" : 15, "user" : "Mike"},
{ "_id" : 4, "pages" : 15, "user" : "Maria"},
{ "_id" : 5, "pages" : 20, "user" : "Maria"},
{ "_id" : 6, "pages" : 1, "user" : "Mike"}
```

Cada documento representa una "Entrada" de información a la DB Mongo.

Lo que necesito es hacer un ranking con toda la información de la DB, realizando la sumatoria de todos los valores de "pages" en cada usuario y obtener un resultado mas o menos como:

```
     { user: "Maria", "TotalPages": 35 },
     { user: "Mike", "TotalPages": 21 },
     { user: "Juanito", "TotalPages": 10 }
```

Basicamente quiero aprender a sacar la sumatoria de los valores en "pages" que tienen en comun el "User" y hacer un Sort de mayor a menor.

Muchas gracias de anemano por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente, lo que se hace aqui, es crear un arreglo `result`, recorremos los objetos que tienes tu y verificamos si en el arreglo `result` ya existe el Usuario recorrido de tu arreglo.

1) Si no existe, se agrega y se agregan la cantidad de paginas por Usuario.

2) Si existe, simplemente se actualizan los valores.

Finalmente se ordena de manera mayor a menor.

```js
var array = [
  { "_id" : 1, "pages" : 5, "user" : "Mike"},
  { "_id" : 2, "pages" : 10, "user" : "Juanito"},
  { "_id" : 3, "pages" : 15, "user" : "Mike"},
  { "_id" : 4, "pages" : 15, "user" : "Maria"},
  { "_id" : 5, "pages" : 20, "user" : "Maria"},
  { "_id" : 6, "pages" : 1, "user" : "Mike"}
]
result = [];
array.forEach(function (personaPage) {
    if (!this[personaPage.user]) {
        this[personaPage.user] = { user: personaPage.user, TotalPages: 0 };
        result.push(this[personaPage.user]);
    }
    this[personaPage.user].TotalPages += personaPage.pages;
});

var resultSort = result.slice(0);
resultSort.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b.TotalPages - a.TotalPages;
});
console.log(resultSort);
```